Jenkins pipeline stage failing before steps are even attempted, no logs for the failure
I am attempting to add a stage to our Jenkins pipeline that will run a 42Crunch conformance scan via a Postman collection. However for some reason the pipeline stage is failing right before or at the steps portion of the stage. Here is what I have added to our pipeline:
stage('42 Crunch Conformance Scan')  
  {
    echo("*** Started 42 Crunch Conformance Scan ***")
    environment {
      http_proxy = '****'
      https_proxy = '****'
    }
    echo("Proxy Set")
      steps{
 
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '42crunch-api-token', variable: 'API_KEY')]) {
          sh 'newman -version'
          sh("newman run integration/42crunch/${appName}42Crunch.postman_collection.json "
                            + "-e integration/smoke/${appName}ApigeeSmokeTest.postman_environment.json --env-var runningOnPipeline=yes --env-var x-api-key=$API_KEY")
        }
      }
      post {
        failure {
          archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/newman/*.html', excludes: null, fingerprint: true
          }
        }
      }

I am getting the Proxy Set log but it immediately fails after that. It is not even hitting the post step. I have the Credentials Binding plugin as well as having added the newman npm package to our NodeJS plugin. I have attempted to wrap the entire stage and then just the steps in a try/catch but it still failed without any logs each time. Any assistance or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

There is nothing wrong with the withCredentials step assuming that the ID is valid. Perhaps you can set an echo inside the withCredentials step to ensure this. Also, is the build getting marked as failed? Do any post block outside the stage level get hit?

try/catch is the last resort option and should be avoided in pipelines because it brings the unnecessary complexity and hides the reasons of the failures if used carelessly.

@MB I've put echos inside of the steps before the withCredentials and within the withCredentials but none of those were ever logged, which tells me it is failing before or on the steps since it doesn'teven make it inside. The Jenkins build fails on this as well.

It looks like you're mixing the scripted and declarative syntax in a way that is not allowed. In the declarative syntax, echo is a step and it cannot work outside the steps block. A correct example would look like this:
stage('42 Crunch Conformance Scan') {
  environment {
    http_proxy = '****'
    https_proxy = '****'
  }
  steps {
    echo("*** Started 42 Crunch Conformance Scan ***")
    echo("Proxy Set")     
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '42crunch-api-token', variable: 'API_KEY')]) {
      sh 'newman -version'
      sh("newman run integration/42crunch/${appName}42Crunch.postman_collection.json "
                            + "-e integration/smoke/${appName}ApigeeSmokeTest.postman_environment.json --env-var runningOnPipeline=yes --env-var x-api-key=$API_KEY")
    }
    post {
      failure {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/newman/*.html', excludes: null, fingerprint: true
      }
    }
  }
}

To make your pipeline code more clean and understandable, you can use the feature of the credentials binding plugin that allows to bind the credentials directly to the environment variable in the environment block. This also allows to prevent the credentials leaks by avoiding the Groovy string interpolation - just replacing the double quotes with the single ones:
stage('42 Crunch Conformance Scan') {
  environment {
    http_proxy = '****'
    https_proxy = '****'
    API_KEY = credentials('42crunch-api-token')
  }
  steps {
    echo("*** Started 42 Crunch Conformance Scan ***")
    echo("Proxy Set")
    script {
      sh 'newman -version'
      sh('newman run integration/42crunch/${appName}42Crunch.postman_collection.json '
                            + '-e integration/smoke/${appName}ApigeeSmokeTest.postman_environment.json --env-var runningOnPipeline=yes --env-var x-api-key=$API_KEY')
    }
    post {
      failure {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/newman/*.html', excludes: null, fingerprint: true
      }
    }
  }
}

Also, writing the additional logging code usually clutters the log unnecessary (especially when using echo instead of println as it duplicates) because Jenkins already logs the start and stop of any block. Instead, if you ultimately need this, consider using label argument of sh step. Note that in this example I also combined both sh calls into one as recommended to reduce the load on Jenkins controller caused by processing Groovy code, and used the multiline string for better readability:
stage('42 Crunch Conformance Scan') {
  environment {
    http_proxy = '****'
    https_proxy = '****'
    API_KEY = credentials('42crunch-api-token')
  }
  steps {
    script {
      sh label: 'Started 42 Crunch Conformance Scan',
        script: '''
          newman -version
          newman run integration/42crunch/${appName}42Crunch.postman_collection.json \
            -e integration/smoke/${appName}ApigeeSmokeTest.postman_environment.json \
            --env-var runningOnPipeline=yes \
            --env-var x-api-key=$API_KEY
        '''
    }
    post {
      failure {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/newman/*.html', excludes: null, fingerprint: true
      }
    }
  }
}


withCredentials doesn't require a script block. None of your pipeline examples require script blocks, actually.

Great, I just forgot that. Thanks for the correction - I edited my answer accordingly.

@AlexanderPletnev I have tried all of these however it is still failing on the steps. After moving the echos inside of the steps now I have no logs whatsoever when it fails. At least previously I was able to see that it was hitting the echos, now it is not even hitting the echos within the steps. I am so confused why it keeps failing on steps without providing any logs or anything to go off of.

@scottyboombox I hope it's not your entire pipeline? A declarative pipeline starts with a pipeline block and has some boilerplate. I assume you know that and that was an excerpt, but could you confirm?

@Iterokun this is just a single stage from our pipeline, thye three stages before this are executing fine, and if I remove this stage everything else will continue to execute as well. It is just this one stage that I am adding in that does not seem to work.

@scottyboombox check if the credentials you're using are present and accessible from the folder where the failing job resides. I've noticed something similar when the credentials were not available. The error message in that case was barely noticeable and just saying something like credentialName: null in the end of the build log.

@AlexanderPletnev Yep, the credentials were not present in the credentials manager, I added in the 42crunch-api-token credential and it made it past that step (also removed the steps because it was not recognizing that for some reason. Now I just have a problem with the newman commands not being recognized.
